# How do I block access to all websites except a few sites in LinuxMint?

Tags: linux-mint, website

I'm trying to prevent access to all websites except a few ones using the hosts file. I found a solution on the web that suggests adding these two lines to the hosts file to allow only YouTube and block everything else.

```
127.0.0.1 * 
EXCLUDE *.youtube.com
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Disable DNS and add in `hosts` the sites with IPs